# How to run systemd services in Docker container without --privileged flag?

Tags: docker, systemd

I'm attempting to build several containers, each running service daemons like firewalld, ntpd, etc. I've read a lot about how using the --privileged flag basically negates the purpose of Docker containers and isn't secure. How do you run these services in a container without privileges? I'm attempting to use the centos:latest Docker image.

Thanks.

Comment: Running service daemons for what, the host? Why use Docker for that?

Comment: @DanielB maybe those were bad examples, but I'm really just looking for a way to run services controlled by systemd inside containers.  For instance, the httpd docker image runs httpd in a container without privs...How does it do that?

Comment: …by not using Systemd? But maybe you don’t actually want to use Docker but instead magically containerize regular software installed on the host system?

Comment: Interesting thing is that Centos supports systemd in container; see https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/systemd/ I think using systemd in docker is not so bad idea.

Comment: `firewalld` is going to have to be able to access the packet filter, which is in kernel space, so that's going to *have* to run privileged.